# Configuring a cakephp controller does not recognize file structure

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I am attempting to start a new cakePHP project under my ~/Sites/cakeapps/cakephp

folder structure. I was able to using the `cake bake` command create a new project and it placed the project inside my `/cakephp` directory. My project file structure now looks like this.

```
/cakeapps/cakephp/app/<Project>/
```

i have followed the tutorial and i have my database.php file configured, core.php configured and created a custom controller `<IjazaController>` that extends the `AppController`. This file

```
class IjazaController extends AppController {


    function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public  function  index(){

    }
}
```

has a corresponding index.ctp file under `/View/Ijaza/index.ctp`. When i try to browse to this url `http://localhost/cakephp/ijaza/` i end up with an error:

```
Error: CakephpController could not be found.

Error: Create the class CakephpController below in file: cakephp/Controller/CakephpController.php

<?php
class CakephpController extends AppController {

}
```

I am not sure why my url routing does not find the index.ctp file, i am using a mac with XAMPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed something up: The folder `cakephp` is not required.

Rearrange your folders into this structure, where `yourproject` is the name of your project (or copy of the app folder...):

```
~/Sites/ 
~/Sites/cakephp/ --> The cakephp library
~/Sites/cakephp/yourproject/ --> Your application code
```

**Example**

```
~/Sites/cakephp/plugins/
~/Sites/cakephp/vendors/
~/Sites/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php
...

~/Sites/cakephp/yourproject/Config/core.php
...
~/Sites/cakephp/yourproject/Controller/IjazaController.php
...
~/Sites/cakephp/yourproject/View/Ijaza/index.ctp
```

Comment: After putting the /cakephp in the same directory level as /cakeapps. my localhost can no longer find the index root. it keeps looking in /Sites/cakeapps. how do i change that so  localhost looks for /cakephp/ and the folder structure you have suggested

Comment: You have to point your apache configuration to the ~/Sites/cakephp/ folder, then you can access it via http://localhost/yourproject/ijaza/

Comment: I have got this file structure set up and xammp is able to read it. i am now having a fatal error  CakePHP core could not be found. I will ask this as a separate question. thanks for your help on the proper folder structure